# how to transfer files using udp in linux environment

Tags: linux, udp, file-transfer

hi can any one tell me how to write code to send files from one linux pc to another linux pc using udp transfer protocol? i had the code for transfering strings from one pc to another pc  i want to know how to transfer files . i would be thankful if anyone helps me
thank you so much in advance..

Comment: Don't; UDP is not a reliable protocol, so you'll have to implement sequencing and retransmission yourself. Prefer TCP for file transfer.

Comment: Do you recall that there's no error correction in UDP? Can you accept that in your file transfers?

Comment: Is there some UDP file transfer application application that implements things like in TCP under the hood? It should work even on systems where TCP works bad and it should be configurable as non-admin.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nontrivial, and also pointless exercise, as to do it efficiently, you end up reinventing TCP.

For an "easy" way of doing it, try implementing TFTP. TFTP is a very stupid protocol where each frame is individually acknowledged and the sender waits for the response before sending the next frame. This is not a good way of doing file transfer and is much worse than TCP.

TFTP I think was designed to be implemented in the minimum amount of code (rather than being efficient). It has historically been used by network boot loaders, which must sometimes live in a tiny rom (a historical limitation).

Depending on the latency and bandwidth of your network, ack'ing individual frames and waiting for the ack before sending the next one, will result in very poor performance (unless your network has extremely low latency *and* low bandwidth, which do not generally go hand-in-hand).